# Return results with unique identifiers across multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to return all results that have the following values

Data:

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|ID
1      | 2     |1      |67
1      | 1     |1      |67
2      | 2     |2      |67
4      | 4     |1      |67
```

Return:

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|ID
1      | 1     |1      |67
2      | 2     |2      |67
```

Paramaters:
Return any data that has:

```
1 in column1 AND 1 in column2 AND 1 in column3
2 in column1 AND 2 in column2 AND 2 in column3
3 in column1 AND 3 in column2 AND 3 in column3
```

Thanks! Right now I' just making multiple queries and compiling the data together.

```
HAVING (((dbo_INVOICE.INV_TOTAL)>0) AND ((dbo_ITEMSORD.INVOICE_ID)="002")  AND
        ((dbo_PACKAGE.INVOICE_ID)="002") AND ((dbo_INVOICE.INVOICE_ID)="002"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First looking at your code you are not comparing aggregations in your `HAVING` clause so it is likely you actually want these conditions in a `WHERE` clause.  Then parenthesis and AND/OR are your friend here so you can establish precedence in your constraints. so for the case you described you could write:

```
   WHERE
    (Column1 = 1 AND Column2 = 1 AND Column3 = 1)
    OR (Column1 = 2 AND Column2 = 2 AND Column3 = 2)
    OR (Column1 = 3 AND Column2 = 3 AND Column3 = 3)
```

And if you actually want to simplify you can test that A = B AND B = C and A is 1,2, or 3.  Because that would mean that A = B = C and they are between 1 AND 3. which can be done like this:

```
WHERE
    Column1 = Column2 AND Column2 = Column3
    AND Column1 IN (1,2,3)
```

And looking at your specific sql statement something like this would likely work for you:

```
WHERE
    dbo_INVOICE.INV_TOTAL > 0
    AND dbo_ITEMSORD.INVOICE_ID = dbo_PACKAGE.INVOICE_ID
    AND dbo_PACKAGE.INVOICE_ID = dbo_INVOICE.INVOICE_ID
    AND dbo_ITEMSORD.INVOICE_ID IN ("001","002","003")
```

Note if you just want all of the columns to be equal and don't care what the values are just take out the `IN` condition.

Comment: I received an error, "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'dbo_INVOICE.INVOICE_ID
WHERE
    dbo_INVOICE.INV_TOTAL > 0
    AND dbo_ITEMSORD.INVOICE_ID = dbo_PACKAGE.INVOICE_ID
    AND dbo_PACKAGE.INVOICE_ID = dbo_INVOICE.INVOICE_ID
    AND dbo_ITEMSORD.INVOICE_ID IN ("001","002","003")'

Comment: @Charles if you post your entire query I will take a look at it to see if I can find the syntax error but as it is I can't make out the entirety.

Comment: I've figured it out. Gotta make sure I do some of the work as well. =) Thanks for all your help!